# Mariadb UPDATE table to move all rows up with one command possible?

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, sql-function

In MariaDB I have this table:

```
OHCL

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(3)|No|
|index_minus|int(10)|No|0
|timestamp|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|year|int(4)|Yes|NULL
|month|int(2)|Yes|NULL
|day|int(2)|Yes|NULL
|hour|int(2)|Yes|NULL
|minute|int(2)|Yes|NULL
|close|float|Yes|NULL
|MFA_short|float|Yes|NULL
|MFA_long|float|Yes|NULL
|volume|float|Yes|NULL
|count|int(10)|Yes|NULL
== Dumping data for table OHCL

|1|0|1619743800|2021|4|30|2|50|0.3036|NULL|NULL|97852.6|41
|2|1|1619744100|2021|4|30|2|55|0.30358|NULL|NULL|221278|45
|3|2|1619744400|2021|4|30|3|0|0.303548|NULL|NULL|41685|30
|4|3|1619744700|2021|4|30|3|5|0.304009|NULL|NULL|158091|23
```

I need to "shift" (or move? not sure which term best describes this) each row except `id` and `index_minus` upwards by 1, therefore discarding row with id = 1. Row 720 should be populated with default values. Default values in the last row are not that important. I will update this row with new data in a further step. I just thought, if this is at all possible, then default values would be the way to go.

The result should be looking like this:

```
|1|0|1619744100|2021|4|30|2|55|0.30358|NULL|NULL|221278|45
|2|1|1619744400|2021|4|30|3|0|0.303548|NULL|NULL|41685|30
|3|2|1619744700|2021|4|30|3|5|0.304009|NULL|NULL|158091|23
|4|3|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

I tried this for a while now but can't find out if this is even possible?

Trying to shift just a single column for testing, the closest I got was something along the lines of this:
`UPDATE OHCL SET minute = LEAD(minute) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS minute`

But that didnt work.

I am new to SQL. Is this even possible with a single command?

Comment: I don't understand what "shift each row upwards by 1" means.  That is not a database operation.  A simple example of before and after results (as *text tables*) would probably clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "Shift" probably is the wrong term then. Is "move the row upwards" more accurate?  I have edited the question, to show a smaller sample table and added an example of the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LAG()` window function to get the previous `id` of each row and join to the table to update the rows:

```
UPDATE OHCL o
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_id
  FROM OHCL
) t ON t.prev_id = o.id
SET o.timestamp = t.timestamp,
    o.year = t.year, 
    o.month = t.month, 
    o.day = t.day, 
    o.hour = t.hour,
    o.minute = t.minute, 
    o.close = t.close, 
    o.MFA_short = t.MFA_short, 
    o.MFA_long = t.MFA_long, 
    o.volume = t.volume, 
    o.count = t.count;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=43b2b5fae8d21125481e18db12c1a860).

If there are no gaps between the `id`s it's easier with a self join:

```
UPDATE OHCL o1
LEFT JOIN OHCL o2
ON o2.id = o1.id + 1
SET o1.timestamp = o2.timestamp,
    o1.year = o2.year, 
    o1.month = o2.month, 
    o1.day = o2.day, 
    o1.hour = o2.hour, 
    o1.minute = o2.minute, 
    o1.close = o2.close, 
    o1.MFA_short = o2.MFA_short, 
    o1.MFA_long = o2.MFA_long, 
    o1.volume = o2.volume, 
    o1.count = o2.count;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=baaf2a6c0f9d263fbe698292e6b3e230).

Comment: That is absolutely 100% it. `hour` was missing. I added it with no problems.
Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this so clearly. Top man!

Comment: @Bravewart you are right, I missed `hour`. I edited.